# Cycle Repitition

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the identity permutation from $0$ to $n-1$, i.e. $s(i)=i$
and in addition two other variables, $i=j=0$.

Now I keep doing the following in a loop:

1) $i = (i+1) \mod n$

2) $j = (j + s(i)) \mod n$

3) $\mathrm{swap}(s(i), s(j))$

When will I again reach the identity permutation, with $i = j = 0$?

Comment: If $s$ is the identity, which role does it play in parts 2 and 3?

Comment: The identity is slowly distorted as i and j vary

Comment: @Jon: According to your own writing, nothing gets distorted there. Maybe you should reconsider your statement of the problem.

Comment: @Alex M. : as 'i' and  'j' are changed in the loop, elements in s are swaped, so it fails to remain identity any longer. The question is how many iterations it will take to again become identity with i=j=0

Comment: I think that here you mean that $s = [s_0, s_1, \dots, s_{n-1}]$  is a sequence of size $n$ so that $s_k =k $, for each $k $

Comment: @JnxF: that is exactly what I mean

Comment: Could someone also sketch a proof of why the repetition occurs